# Is it possible to make a child division float on top of all other divisions, including those with z-index set higher than the parent?

Tags: css, xhtml

I'm sorry if this question has been asked already but I did search and couldn't find it. 
Basically I have a drop down menu in my page that normally needs to appear on top of the main content. But then within that content is a light-box type thing that needs to float on top of that.

So code is something like:

```
<div style="z-index:2"> 
   Drop Menu here
</div>
<div style="z-index:1">
   Content Here... 
   <a href="#">Lightbox button here</a>
   <div>
        Lightbox content (hidden initially)
   </div>
   <div>
        Lightbox background (hidden initially)
   </div>
</div>
```

So now the problem I'm having is if i try and set that lightbox background to a high z-index it's not overriding that of the menu because its parent is lower z-index than the sibling menu division. If I set the content container to a higher level then the drop down is no longer appearing on top of the content and is therefore unclickable.
I know it's probably an obvious thing I'm missing here, or maybe the lightbox plugin I'm using is not that good or something? 
And I'm using joomla CMS so I am limited to where I can create the lightbox division.

Otherwise the other option I thought is to set the z-index on the menu to the child division (the actual menu) but the problem is it's a framework system so I'd need to remove z-index from the base template as well, and it would then get overwritten with an update, unless there's a z-index command that sets it to "ignore" or something?

**Ok Nevermind, I set the z-index to auto instead and it seems to be working, don't know if this is the best solution though, so I'll welcome any other possible solutions.**

Comment: You can't "float on top of something", that's not how floats work. You can absolutely position something to go wherever you want it to though

Comment: Ok fine I mean in the sense of that transparent background goes on top of everything else... if I set the position to absolute it's only contained within that division, not spread to the whole page

Comment: Oh you aren't talking about position, your talking about the z-index, you want to bring it in front of them? Use z-index

Comment: Yeah! z-index wasn't working with siblings set with specific values. It seems to be cross-browser working with setting z-index to auto however.

Comment: Setting `z-index` to a number on an element without actually positioning it is not going to have any effect. Setting `z-index: auto` will have the same effect. How are you positioning these boxes?

Comment: Standard div "block" display, relative positioning. z-index:auto works though, even on different browsers, don't ask me why though

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid it's your HTML that is the problem. You should put the lightbox containers outside the content div as a child of the body tag.

Example:

```
<div style="z-index:2"> 
   Drop Menu here
</div>
<div style="z-index:1">
   Content Here... 
   <a href="#">Lightbox button here</a>
</div>

<div style="z-index:101">
    Lightbox content (hidden initially)
</div>
<div style="z-index:100">
    Lightbox background (hidden initially)
</div>
```

Note: You should of course assign id's to all the above instead and use an external style sheet.

Comment: Yes that's the problem though. I can't do this as it's a self-contained component for Joomla, which puts all the content outputted from that into one division on the template, the menu is in another division, and the template is on a restrictive framework (T3 framework) so I can't just add a div to the html. Maybe i'll need to change the JS to append the background div to the html body directly? 
But thanks anyway for the information. Guess I'll be grinding on this one a bit longer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So the only way it worked perfectly was to append the divisions to the body using jquery. So in my light box script I added :

```
jQuery('body').append(modalBG);
jQuery('body').append(modal);
```

Where the modal and modalBG are the divs with the pop up content and background respectively.

Adding that into the function that creates the lightbox it added them as the last division children in the body which meant the naturally appeared on top of all the other divs, but I suppose you could set a fixed z-index for this as well.
I realise this is probably something quite obvious to pros, but I battled with it so maybe someone else who's struggling with a restrictive template and a CMS system will appreciate the info.